# Почему не выполняется скрипт из /etc/profile.d?

Tags: linux

Я для сборки postgresql использовал этот [туториал](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-from-source-code-in-linux/). В нём надо выполнить `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/PostgreSQL-10/bin' > /etc/profile.d/postgres.sh`, однако после входа в пользователя postgres в переменную PATH ничего не добавилось. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Скрипты в `/etc/profile.d/` запускаются из `/etc/profile`, который в свою очередь выполняется только для оболочек входа (login shell).

Дальнейших вариантов действий несколько:

- Перелогинится.
- Вручную выполнить `. /etc/profile` (оно же `source /etc/profile`) до или после `su`.
- Запустить оболочку входа, например `bash -l`.
- Указать `su`, чтобы он запустил таковую: `su -l <user>`.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы при выполнение команды su postgres выполнялся скрипт?

Comment: @Andru, не совсем понял о чём ты, возможно тебя интересует `su postgres -c <скрипт>`

Comment: Нет. Мне надо чтобы после выполнения команды su postgres я попадал в консоль пользователя postgres и в переменной PATH уже был добавлен путь к базе данных. То есть `/opt/PostgreSQL-10/bin`

Comment: >>Мне надо чтобы после выполнения команды su postgres я попадал в консоль пользователя postgres<< — а куда ты сейчас попадаешь? — >>и в переменной PATH уже был добавлен путь к базе данных. То есть /opt/PostgreSQL-10/bin<<  — если `/etc/profile.d/postgres.sh` корректно отрабатывает, то он должен быть в PATH у всех пользователей.

Comment: Его нет ни у кого. Как сделать чтобы был только у postgres?

Comment: @Andru, гмм... вероятно ты сделал что-то не так (отошёл от инструкции) или конфигурация системы отличается от обычной... можно поиграть «в виртуальную консоль» в чатике, если хочешь выянить что именно... по поводу того, «как сделать, чтобы был только у postgres» — обычно это излишне и только мешает... но если очень хочется, то пользователю нужно будет создать домашний каталог и прописать это там...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76497/discussion-between-andru-and-fat-zer).